# create table postgres is showing an error near ")" on creation

Tags: postgresql

keep getting error syntax error at or near ")". I have looked around and just can not find an answer. I have created a table with string key values and without string key values. Does anyone know. I have also checked day, year, and time as values that postgres already uses.

```
CREATE TABLE "appointments" (
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "day" VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    "dayName" VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    "monthName" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "monthIndex" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "year" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "email" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "message" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "time" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Note that the length restriction of 255 does not magically make thinks more efficient or faster than e.g. a length of 250 or 258. But a column named `year` should be declared as an `integer` and a column named `"time"` should probably be declared as `time`. A column named `message`  is probably better declared as `text`

Comment: i'm creating a plugin in javascript and need custom values. https://github.com/andimi3/npm-quickCal/blob/main/calendar.js. the 255 i know doesnt matter im just doing that for whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma in last line

```
CREATE TABLE "appointments" (
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "day" VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    "dayName" VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    "monthName" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "monthIndex" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "year" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "email" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "message" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
    "time" VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: gracias gracias gracias gracias. You are rewarded with a drink tonight.

Comment: i am able to in three minutes